# How to log executed sql statement

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommand

**Scenario**

I am executing a stored procedure using ADO.NET SqlCommand:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_Trk_GetSuspiciusVisitor";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("channel","gb"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("data", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)));
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

I would like to log the executed sql statement. In this case I would like to log the string:

```
sp_Trk_GetSuspiciusVisitor 'gb', '2012-08-12'
```

**Question**

Is there any property of the `SqlCommand` or of the `SqlConnection` classes that does the job?

Comment: That statement is never executed - when using parameters, the **parametrized** query and the list of parameters and their values is sent to SQL Server. Only there are parameter values introduced into the query.

Comment: What is the *purpose* of the logging? More context might help

Comment: @Marc Gravell: if I log the sql statement it can be quickly executed in a sql client in case of error, exception, check or whatever.

Comment: In that case, I'll undelete my answer; I think the tool could really help for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, unfortunatelly you would have to loop through all the paramenters to get their values and  concatenate it with the command text

Comment: yep, that's how I ended up doing it. If memory serves I might have made the access pretty (an extension method of ToString on the Command springs to mind) but under the hood I ended up doing a foreach on the parameters. But this had its advantages as I was also able to output values and directions. Surprising how useful this was for debugging!

Answer (score 4):

There is no *magic* way to do this, but there are a number of tools that can play nicely with ADO.NET to capture what is happening. For example, [mini-profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) does this by wrapping ADO.NET, which usually involves just a single change to your "create a connection" code - it then logs operations internally. The code is open source, so it would be trivial to tweak it to your own logging framework.

As an example, if I go (logged in) to SEDE, and look at a random page, [here, say](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag), I can see all the logged SQL operations (no code changes were necessary to get this logging), [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/mini-profiler-resources/results?id=5b261f3d-d320-40bd-b264-c9e015d7d250) - or in case that becomes unavailable:

[image]

The only minor glitch is your explicit use of `SqlParameter`, which might need changing to `cmd.CreateParameter()`. Alternatively, use something like dapper to make it easier:

```
conn.Execute("sp_Trk_GetSuspiciusVisitor",
    new { channel = "gb", data = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Note that the `declare` statements show above were **not** part of the original query; the tool has added these to make it easy to run the query in SSMS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

or edit your stored procedure to do the logging by editing it to add the equivalent of:

```
insert into my_sp_log 
values ('sp_trk_getSuspiciousVisitor', @channel, @data, getdate())
```

Comment: yeah, but if the call fails, you get not log att all